# Removing page numbers from PDF created using knitr from a moderncv template

Tags: latex, rstudio, pandoc

This question covers R Studio, pandoc and also LaTeX I suppose. The following is what my YAML looks like in R Studio:

```
---
name: Me Me Me
surname: Myself
position: "Job seeker"
address: "Some address in Newfoundland"
phone: +1 800 111111
www: google.com
email: "myemail@yahoo.com"
linkedin: john-joseph-jingle-jabber-smith/123
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %Y')`"
output: vitae::moderncv
theme: classic 
---
```

In the footer, the page number is displayed. People with a similar problem have fixed this by changing the LaTeX preamble, but I have no such file, instead I have a collection of one .cls and several .sty files. Which of these would I need to change in order to suppress page numbering? Or is it possible to add pandoc args for this in the preamble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

moderncv has the `\nopagenumbers` macro to switch off page numbers:

```
---
name: Me Me Me
surname: Myself
position: "Job seeker"
address: "Some address in Newfoundland"
phone: +1 800 111111
www: google.com
email: "myemail@yahoo.com"
linkedin: john-joseph-jingle-jabber-smith/123
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %Y')`"
output: 
  vitae::moderncv:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \nopagenumbers
theme: classic 
---

test

\clearpage

test
```